# Bind svg data directly to Image or SvgImageSource

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way to load a svg directly in the Image control, without saving a file that should be loaded as the source of the Image control?

I need to display a svg that I receive from some web api in my UWP application. Currently I save a temp file that I load using the SvgImageSource, like this:

In Xaml:

```
<Image Name="image"/>
```

In Code Behind:

```
var newFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".svg");
var writeStream = await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

await writeStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someCustomSvg), 0, someCustomSvg.Length);

writeStream.Dispose();

image.Source = new SvgImageSource(new Uri(newFile.Path));
```

This works, but is not that efficient.

I would need something that loads the svg into the Image Control without having to save a temp file on the disk.

I know that I can load the svg in a WebView control, but that is also not as efficient as rendering the svg with the Image control.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HttpClient` to get the stream from web api. And then convert the stream to [`SvgImageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource). For more detail please refer to the following code.

```
 private async void MyBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
     {
         var svg = new SvgImageSource();
         try
         {
             var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.iconsvg.com/Home/downloadPicture?route=1333158662629220352&name=%E5%9C%86%E5%BD%A2%E7%9A%84_circular164"));

             if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
             {
                 using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                 {
                     using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                     {
                         await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                         memStream.Position = 0;
                         await svg.SetSourceAsync(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
                         MyImageView.Source = svg;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }
     }
 }

<Image x:Name="MyImageView" Source="{Binding imageSource ,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource MyConvert }}" />
```

I have uploaded [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SVGFileLoadDerictlyTest.git) to github. Please check.